# Manipulating gifs frame by frame in C with libgd

Tags: c, gif

I have a program I use to manipulate various image files. Currently it only works with static images. I want to provide support for gifs and I've been looking through the lackluster [doc](https://libgd.github.io/manuals/2.2.5/files/gd_gif_in-c.htm)u[ment](https://libgd.github.io/manuals/2.2.5/files/gd_gif_out-c.html)a[tion](https://libgd.github.io/manuals/2.2.5/files/gd-h.html#GifAnim) but cannot find any reference to how to manipulate gifs frame by frame.

Ideally I'd like to work through the gif one frame at a time, using my other functions to manipulate each of the frames in a file and then repackage the image.

Comment: Please insert the relevant code parts if you want somebody to help you.

Comment: Is using `libgd` a must? I\`ve got a nice little header-only [GIF loader](https://github.com/hidefromkgb/gif_load) that seems to be just what you need: give it a callback, and it\`ll get called once every frame, providing the decoded pixel data.

Comment: @hidefromkgb definitely not a must. I just saw that it had some level of gif support so I thought it ought to work, but per Jose's comment below it looks like it won't work the way I want. I will take a look at GIF loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully to [the source code](https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/master/src/gd_gif_in.c), you can easily find a weak implementation when using animated frames.

> The code does not lie: when you call `gdImageCreateFromGif(FILE *fdFile)` or `gdImageCreateFromGifPtr (int size, void *data)`, it calls directly to `gdImageCreateFromGifCtx(gdIOCtxPtr fd)`, so you must *read'n'search* in that function where is the mess. The documentation has no info about it, because this library is very, very old.

In the source code (*fd06f7f  on 22 Jun*) line 258 (`gdImageCreateFromGifCtx(gdIOCtxPtr fd)`):

```
for (;;) {
    int top, left;
    int width, height;

    if(!ReadOK(fd, &c, 1)) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (c == ';') { /* GIF terminator */
        goto terminated;
    }

    if(c == '!') { /* Extension */
        if(!ReadOK(fd, &c, 1)) {
            return 0;
        }

        DoExtension(fd, c, &Transparent, &ZeroDataBlock);
        continue;
    }

    if(c != ',') { /* Not a valid start character */
        continue;
    }

    /*1.4//++imageCount; */

    if(!ReadOK(fd, buf, 9)) {
        return 0;
    }

    useGlobalColormap = !BitSet(buf[8], LOCALCOLORMAP);

    bitPixel = 1 << ((buf[8] & 0x07) + 1);
    left = LM_to_uint(buf[0], buf[1]);
    top = LM_to_uint(buf[2], buf[3]);
    width = LM_to_uint(buf[4], buf[5]);
    height = LM_to_uint(buf[6], buf[7]);

    if(((left + width) > screen_width) || ((top + height) > screen_height)) {
        if(VERBOSE) {
            printf("Frame is not confined to screen dimension.\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    if(!(im = gdImageCreate(width, height))) {
        return 0;
    }

    im->interlace = BitSet(buf[8], INTERLACE);
    if(!useGlobalColormap) {
        if(ReadColorMap(fd, bitPixel, localColorMap)) {
            gdImageDestroy(im);
            return 0;
        }

        ReadImage(im, fd, width, height, localColorMap, BitSet(buf[8], INTERLACE), &ZeroDataBlock);
    } else {
        if(!haveGlobalColormap) {
            gdImageDestroy(im);
            return 0;
        }

        ReadImage(im, fd, width, height, ColorMap, BitSet(buf[8], INTERLACE), &ZeroDataBlock);
    }

    if(Transparent != (-1)) {
        gdImageColorTransparent(im, Transparent);
    }

    goto terminated;
}
```

That `goto` finishes the loop without attempt to read another frame, even.

That's because this implementation is intended to read **explicitly** one frame from a gif. Only **one**.

I worked with this library. Has other flaws, too. The transparency for PNG files are 7 bits, not 8 bits (one of the main reasons I used it and discard it later).

You can pack [animated gifs](https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/master/src/gd_gif_out.c) with `gdImageGifAnimBegin(gdImagePtr im, FILE *outFile, int GlobalCM, int Loops)`

**[TL;DR]:** libgd has no multiple frames option when loading. It's not intended to load animated gifs.